# Xamarin Forms using MVVM Light - Remove Navigation pages from stack

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I have a simple Xamarin forms based application which submits an application to a service, upon which I want to clear the navigation stack, so that a new application can be entered. I'm using the MVVM Light framework but the built in navigation service has no method clear the stack.

I know this is possible with out of the box Xamarin using `Navigation.RemovePage`, but not sure how to implement this within MVVM Lights navigation service.

I have the following in the NavigateTo method using parameter as an indicator to clear the stack:

```
if (parameter == null)
{
    foreach (var pageList in _navigation.Pages)
    {
        //Remove from navigation stack                                   
    }
}
```

I was hoping I could fire something from here to clear the stack so that the pages are refreshed, or is there a better way of doing it, possibly from the viewmodel directly?

Thanks

Comment: If your `_navigation` field is a `Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage`, you could just use `_navigation.PopToRootAsync()`

Comment: That does indeed remove everything from the stack however my forms are still showing the previous application data, as if they were cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, using MVVMLight, you can use :

`SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<ViewModel>();`

This completely removes the view model/bindings from cache and all previous instances.

I found just popping from the stack, (using `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();`) didn't clear the model data, just the navigation stack.